# Is there a way to add more languages for soldiers' voices?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

Welp, they made 6 additional languages for the soldiers to speak (which are French, German, Italian, Polish, Russian and Spanish) but whenever you have a chinese / japanese / korean soldier, there isn't such language for them.

Are there language packs to download and install so that I can make asian people speak in their actual language?

Comment: The Long War devs are adding more voices, so it's possible. However, they have no plans for more languages.

Answer (score 2):

No. It may be possible for mods to add new languages - Studoku mentions in comments that The Long War may do this - but there is no "official" way to get extra voice languages.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked around nexus mods for one, but there aren't any. My guess is that some of the larger mod overhauls may add them in the future, but for now, the answer is no.